# Deleting old migrations pushed to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

```
 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
D, [2018-11-06T03:46:52.337306 #4] DEBUG -- :  (1.7ms)  `SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
   up     20180903011647  Create movies
   up     20180903012838  Add fields to movies
   up     20180922012345  Add more fields to movies
   up     20181023010527  Create reviews
   up     20181023015412  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20181102193810  ********** NO FILE **********
  down    20181105211502  Add extra image fields to movies
  down    20181106003841  Add main image to movies
```

How can I delete old migrations in heroku? . These old tables seem to be causing errors when I am trying to run `heroku run rake db:migrate` with the last two migrations.

I want to delete `20181023015412` and `20181102193810`. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you please show what error you are getting?

Comment: Instead of deleting old migrations just create new blank file with combination of this `20181023015412` ? and then add nothing in that file, just add `def change end`

Comment: Here is the error I am getting when I am trying to save an image that I uploaded. `NoMethodError `(undefined method `main_image_will_change!' for #<Movie:0x00559789911998>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have run down for last two migrations as per your provided data. So I think those two versions are removed from SchemaMigration table.

now you just need to pass commit in which you need to delete those migration files. It will work fine for later migration. Please confirm before following this.

**Note** In Fact, If you getting errors,please post errors

Comment: I ended up deleting my database in Heroku and it was removed. It was all sample data anyways. Thank you.